# Ingest Live Data from One Drive File to Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, onedrive, data-ingestion

I want to create a table in Big Query, that automatically updated whenever an excel sheet stored in One Drive is updated.

The same is possible using Google Sheets, however I am unable to do the same for an Excel sheet stored in OneDrive.

Due to policy issues, I am unable to use google sheets directly, and can't use any extensions to pull data from One Drive to Google sheet as well, since its a corporate one drive that doesn't allow connections to one drive.

The only way to upload data to Big Query other than Google suite is to manually upload a csv file, but that is not feasible as this is a sheet that is updated hourly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python connector to OneDrive https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python you can use to check the OneDrive file hourly with Python, then download the updated Excel Sheet and upload the new data to BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest

Python script can be scheduled hourly with Task Scheduler on Windows or Cron on Linux.[image: Schedule Python script]